# How to update the 'status' value from nested document in MongoDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update a document in a collection:

```
mydb = client['Fruits']
fruit_information = mydb.fruits

record = {'fruit_name': {'apple':{'status':'0'},'banana':{'status':'0'}}}
fruit_information.insert(record)
```

So I want to update the 'status' : '1', how can I do that?
If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert call is deprecated. I recommend to use the insert_one. This method returns an insert result wich contains the id of the inserted document. You can then pass this id to update_one call as a document filter and update the nested field like this.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
mydb = client['Fruits']
fruit_information = mydb.fruits

record = {'fruit_name': {'apple':{'status':'0'},'banana':{'status':'0'}}}
result = fruit_information.insert_one(record)

fruit_information.update_one({'_id' : result.inserted_id}, {'$set': {'fruit_name.apple.status' : 1}})
fruit_information.update_one({'_id' : result.inserted_id}, {'$set': {'fruit_name.banana.status' : 1}})
```